# How do I prevent Power BI line chart drawing a line through time series points when there is no value for some intervals?

Tags: powerbi, time-series, linechart, timeserieschart

I have created a line chart in Power BI to visualise the following fictional data.

| **LA | Year | Value** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WF | 2020 | 4 |
| WF | 2021 | 10 |
| WF | 2022 |  |
| Hac | 2020 | 6 |
| Hac | 2021 | 23 |
| Hac | 2022 | 28 |
| Har | 2020 | 3 |
| Har | 2021 | 8 |
| Har | 2022 | 10 |
| Hac | 2023 | 11 |
| WF | 2023 | 12 |
| Har | 2023 | 5 |

As you can see in the third row, there is no value for WF in 2022 but further down WF has a value of 12 in 2023. When I plot WF values by year and also national average values, Power BI draws a straight line for WF from 2021 (10) through 2022 to 2023(12). However, I do not want a line to be drawn through 2022 if a value does not exist. I just want the line to stop at 2021 and plot a dot for the 2023 value.

[Line chart plot of above data in Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGLD6.png)

Can anyone help with this please?

I have tried changing the x axis from continuous to categorical but that did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this with a bit of digging around. I was able to plot a broken line but doing the following.

1. Change the x-axis from continuous to categorical. (Ensure that the Year is a number and not text).
2. Then right click on the visual and sort by Year.

The line between the 2021 value and the 2023 value will disappear and a single point will be plotted for 2023 value. That's it! Hopefully this will be useful to someone.